# How do I select specific columns in a sql prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, innodb, select

I have created a prepared statement to output a file and add a date to the filename. That part works if I select the entire database. I want to select specific columns to include in the query, not all of them.

I'm a newbie to SQL syntax, so please be aware of that when answering. :)

**Here is what I started with before the date-in-filename was a requirement:**

```
    USE dbx;
SELECT
   custtype.custtype,
   custtype.custtypedesc,
   USER.jobtitle,
   USER.branch,
   log.custid,
   log.username,
   log.actualuser,
   log.timestamp,
   log.action,
   log.data INTO outfile '/inetpub/wwwroot/reports/Activity_Log.csv' fields terminated BY ',' optionally enclosed BY '"' lines terminated BY '\n' 
FROM
   log 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      USER 
      ON log.custid = USER.custid 
      AND log.username = USER.username 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      custtype 
      ON custtype.custtype = USER.custtype 
WHERE
   USER.email NOT LIKE " % @sample.com" 
   AND USER.email NOT LIKE " % @google.com" 
   AND log.username NOT LIKE "Guest % "
```

You can see that I am selecting individual columns as per my requirement. That works well. However, I can't figure out how to select individual columns like this in the next query...

**Here is what I have now after the date requirement was added:**

```
SET
   @TS = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '_%m_%d_%Y');
SET
   @FOLDER = '/inetpub/wwwroot/reports/';
SET
   @PREFIX = 'Activity_Report_';
SET
   @EXT = '.csv';
USE webcat_336;
SET
   @CMD = concat("
   SELECT
      custtype.CustType, custtype.CustTypeDesc 
   FROM
      log INTO OUTFILE", @FOLDER , @TS, @EXT);
"' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"' TERMINATED BY ';
' ESCAPED BY '\"'",
 " LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
"
```

If I replace "custtype.CustType, custtype.CustTypeDesc" in the 2nd example with *, the file generates properly and it's named "Activity_Log_m_d_Y.csv" as expected.

**LATEST UPDATE**

I can now select all the columns I originally intended with the following code. However, the WHERE clause breaks it.

```
USE db_name;
SELECT
   @cmd : = concat( "
   SELECT
      custtype.CustType , custtype.CustTypeDesc , user.JobTitle , user.Branch , log.CustID , log.Username , log.ActualUser , log.Timestamp , log.Action , log.Data into OUTFILE '/inetpub/wwwroot/reports/Activity_Report_",
 DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%m_%d_%Y'), ".csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
   FROM
      log 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
         user 
         ON log.CustID = user.CustID 
         AND log.Username = user.Username 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
         custtype 
         ON custtype.CustType = user.CustType 
   WHERE
      USER.email NOT LIKE " % @sample.com" 
      AND USER.email NOT LIKE " % @google.com" 
      AND log.username NOT LIKE "Guest % " ");
PREPARE stmt 
   FROM
      @cmd;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

**Question**

How can I select only specific columns as opposed to all columns in the example above?

Comment: FROM log  but columns stem from table custtype - is that intended?

Comment: @Akina, I removed the tag.

Comment: @eagle275, yes, that was intended. I'm pulling from 3 different tables different tables.

Answer (score 0):

After my understanding of mysql - you don't change anything about

FROM, JOIN and most likely WHERE

only change desired columns .... if your 3 tables work together you cant easily break up this "team" for the report even if you only want to see a single column

```
SET
   @TS = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '_%m_%d_%Y');
SET
   @FOLDER = '/inetpub/wwwroot/reports/';
SET
   @PREFIX = 'Activity_Report_';
SET
   @EXT = '.csv';
USE webcat_336;
SET
   @CMD = concat("
   SELECT
      custtype.CustType, custtype.CustTypeDesc 
    INTO OUTFILE", @FOLDER , @TS, @EXT ," FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '\"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM
   log 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      USER 
      ON log.custid = USER.custid 
      AND log.username = USER.username 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      custtype 
      ON custtype.custtype = USER.custtype 
WHERE
   USER.email NOT LIKE " % @sample.com" 
   AND USER.email NOT LIKE " % @google.com" 
   AND log.username NOT LIKE "Guest % ");

"
```

Comment: I added the FROM, JOIN and WHERE clauses back into my latest code for completeness. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Missing some quotes:

```
CONCAT("... INTO OUTFILE", @FOLDER , @TS, @EXT ," FIELDS ...
```

-->

```
CONCAT("... INTO OUTFILE'", @FOLDER , @TS, @EXT ,"' FIELDS ...
```